# Is this code an accurate representation for explaining Accumulated Gradients in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

model = SimpleModel()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

# Turn on gradient accumulation
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
    param.grad = None

# Set AccumulateGrad to True
optimizer.zero_grad()
accumulated_gradients = None

for i in range(5):  # Simulating 5 batches
    input_data = torch.randn(1, 10)
    output = model(input_data)
    loss = output.sum()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)  # Accumulate gradients

    if accumulated_gradients is None:
        accumulated_gradients = [param.grad for param in model.parameters()]
    else:
        for j, param in enumerate(model.parameters()):
            accumulated_gradients[j] += param.grad
    
    print(f"Gradients after batch {i + 1} accumulated.")

# Update the parameters using the accumulated gradients
for param, accumulated_gradient in zip(model.parameters(), accumulated_gradients):
    param.grad = accumulated_gradient
optimizer.step()

# Print the updated weights
print(f"Weights after 5 batches update: {model.fc.weight.data}")
```

In this code, I tried to set an example of How the Accumulated Gradient works in PyTorch.

This code first collects the gradients or sums the gradient values. After the fifth Iteration, it updates the weights.
Is this code right ??

Comment: Have you tried running it to see what happens?

Comment: OUTPUT::
Gradients after batch 1 accumulated.
Gradients after batch 2 accumulated.
Gradients after batch 3 accumulated.
Gradients after batch 4 accumulated.
Gradients after batch 5 accumulated.
Weights after 5 batches update: tensor([[ 2.1714e+00, -3.8258e-03,  1.3457e+00,  1.0224e+00, -5.7007e-01,
         -1.2916e+00,  4.2983e+00, -1.7602e-01,  4.4261e+00,  1.3223e+00]])
NOW I DON'T KNOW ABOUT MY CONCEPT OF THIS IS CORRECT OR NOT.

Comment: Never done this before but it sounds like all 5 batches ran and came up with those tensor values, does it export them anywhere like a mysql database?  If so, check and see if it did that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the gradients to get accumulated in PyTorch, you just need to not use `zero_grad()` in your code. Let me give you an example,

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(5, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

model = SimpleModel()
print(model.fc.weight.grad)
>>> None
```

Here, I create a simple model. Before we start, I check the gradient for the weight of the layer *fc*, and as you can see it has no gradient right now (its gradient is *None*). Now, let's accumulate some gradients!

```
input_data = torch.randn(1, 5)
for i in range(5):
    output = model(input_data)
    loss = output.sum()
    loss.backward()
    
    print(f'grad after {i+1} iteration:', model.fc.weight.grad)
    model.zero_grad()
>>> grad after 1 iteration: tensor([[-0.3563,  0.3777,  1.7307,  1.8210,  0.1536]])
>>> grad after 2 iteration: tensor([[-0.7126,  0.7553,  3.4615,  3.6419,  0.3071]])
>>> grad after 3 iteration: tensor([[-1.0690,  1.1330,  5.1922,  5.4629,  0.4607]])
>>> grad after 4 iteration: tensor([[-1.4253,  1.5107,  6.9229,  7.2839,  0.6143]])
>>> grad after 5 iteration: tensor([[-1.7816,  1.8883,  8.6536,  9.1048,  0.7679]])
```

I fed the network with `input_data`, calculated some loss, and finally started the backward process by writing `loss.backward()`. Then I print the gradient of the weight. You see, the gradients are summing up (accumulating). Since my input and loss are not changing in each iteration, the weight receives the same gradient and addes it to what it accumulated so far. Therefore, in this example, the gradient accumulated after 5 iterations is 5 times the gradient after 1 iteration. Finally, to update the weight using the accumulated gradients you can add the following code,

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad() # Maybe zero out the gradients if you don't want them anymore
```